# Using tensorflow on colab wihtout having to restart runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I'm running some TensorFlow code on google colab. I'm using tf2 and I want to perform multiple tests on the same model. Thus I'm initializing some variables, preprocessing my data and then I train the model.

My problem is that when I'm changing some arguments and trying to rerun the network I get the following error:

```
tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

I know I can just remove the `@tf.function`  decorator, but then it runs much slower. 
I also tried running `K.clear_outputs()` but it doesn't help.

Is there something I can do instead of removing the tf.function decorator or restarting runtime?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate your error using the below code -

**Code to recreate the error -**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf

opt1 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 1e-2)
opt2 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 1e-3) 

@tf.function
def train_step_with_opt(a, x, y, optimizer):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        L = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(a*x - y))
    tr_weights = [a]
    gradients = tape.gradient(L, tr_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, tr_weights))
    return a

a = tf.Variable(2.)
x = tf.Variable([-1.,-1.,-1.], dtype = tf.float32)
y = tf.Variable([2.,2.,2.], dtype = tf.float32)


train_step_with_opt(a, x, y, opt1) # works
print("First Run was fine")
train_step_with_opt(a, x, y, opt2) # fails
print("Second Run was fine")
```

**Output -**

```
First Run was fine
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-52022dc5007d> in <module>()
     21 train_step_with_opt(a, x, y, opt1) # works
     22 print("First Run was fine")
---> 23 train_step_with_opt(a, x, y, opt2) # fails
     24 print("Second Run was fine")

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-1-4386b333360b>:13 train_step_with_opt  *
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, tr_weights))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:478 apply_gradients  **
        self._create_all_weights(var_list)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:661 _create_all_weights
        _ = self.iterations
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:668 __getattribute__
        return super(OptimizerV2, self).__getattribute__(name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:793 iterations
        aggregation=tf_variables.VariableAggregation.ONLY_FIRST_REPLICA)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:997 add_weight
        aggregation=aggregation)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py:743 _add_variable_with_custom_getter
        **kwargs_for_getter)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py:141 make_variable
        shape=variable_shape if variable_shape else None)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:259 __call__
        return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:220 _variable_v1_call
        shape=shape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:66 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:511 invalid_creator_scope
        "tf.function-decorated function tried to create "

    ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

**Solution -** As you are trying to use function decorator in TF 2.0, please enable run function eagerly after importing TensorFlow. I fixed this problem by adding `tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)` after `import tensorflow`.

You can find more about `tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly` in the official tensorflow website [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2#use_tfconfigexperimental_run_functions_eagerly_when_debugging).

**Fixed Code -**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)

opt1 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 1e-2)
opt2 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 1e-3) 

@tf.function
def train_step_with_opt(a, x, y, optimizer):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        L = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(a*x - y))
    tr_weights = [a]
    gradients = tape.gradient(L, tr_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, tr_weights))
    return a

a = tf.Variable(2.)
x = tf.Variable([-1.,-1.,-1.], dtype = tf.float32)
y = tf.Variable([2.,2.,2.], dtype = tf.float32)


train_step_with_opt(a, x, y, opt1) # works
print("First Run was fine")
train_step_with_opt(a, x, y, opt2) # fails
print("Second Run was fine")
```

Output -

```
First Run was fine
Second Run was fine
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Dvir Itzko - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.